# gspread.exceptions.APIError error code 500

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am using the python gspread library to get information off of google sheets. I have had no prior problems accessing any sheets but one sheet keeps throwing this error with doc.worksheet("{worksheet_name}") or doc.worksheets():

gspread.exceptions.APIError: {
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}

I have ruled out the following possible causes:

- program doesn't have access to the doc
- too many worksheets in the doc
- over api limit

I even created a copy of the doc and tried to access that and the same error occurred.

Comment: Can you provide the information about `one sheet` of `one sheet keeps throwing this error with doc.worksheet("{worksheet_name}") or doc.worksheets():`. For example, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating the issue? At that time, can you also provide your script? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a 100 second delay every 100 requests

[Usage limit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ai5NB.png)

Comment: Was a solution for me as well, but it's weird because a 30 second time delay used to work for me and out of the blue I needed to increase it.

Comment: Could you add a simple example of adding delay, please?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had the same error. I just created another spreadsheet and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused because the data is large.You can improvise by uploading the data in chunks but you need to add rows to the sheet of the additional chunks and specify the range in the sheet you want to append the data
i.e

```
worksheet.update([[]]) #list of lists of first chunk
worksheet.add_rows() #number of rows you want to append
worksheet.update(range,[[]]) #range where you want to place the second chunk and list of the lists of the second chunk
```