# Getting error 500 for read requests to google spreadsheet using gspread

Tags: google-sheets-api

I have a script python script trying to access a google spreadsheet, but I am getting a 500 error from trying to get the list of worksheets with gc.worksheets()

```
APIError: {'code': 500, 'message': 'Internal error encountered.', 'status': 'INTERNAL'}
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
APIError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_14907/1619355115.py in <module>
----> 1 gc.worksheets()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gspread/models.py in worksheets(self)
    351         in a spreadsheet.
    352         """
--> 353         sheet_data = self.fetch_sheet_metadata()
    354         return [Worksheet(self, x['properties']) for x in sheet_data['sheets']]
    355 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gspread/models.py in fetch_sheet_metadata(self, params)
    293         url = SPREADSHEET_URL % self.id
    294 
--> 295         r = self.client.request('get', url, params=params)
    296 
    297         return r.json()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gspread/client.py in request(self, method, endpoint, params, data, json, files, headers)
     74             return response
     75         else:
---> 76             raise APIError(response)
     77 
     78     def list_spreadsheet_files(self, title=None):

APIError: {'code': 500, 'message': 'Internal error encountered.', 'status': 'INTERNAL'}
```

The Code I am using is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

CREDENTIALS_JSON = 'credentials.json'

SCOPES = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(CREDENTIALS_JSON, SCOPES)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)

gc = client.open_by_url('<I use the url of the file here>')

worksheets = gc.worksheets() # This like is returning an error

sheet1 = gc.get_worksheet_by_id(<sheet id>) # This line is also returning an error
```

Everything was working just fine a day before, and I haven't made any changes to the script.

Comment: We can't see your code, so all we can do is guess that there is a bug in your code. [Or maybe rate limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58867054/gspread-exceptions-apierror-error-code-500)? [Or maybe permissions](https://github.com/burnash/gspread/issues/714)?

Comment: Can you provide the relevant parts of the code you're working on?

Comment: @Iamblichus I have updated the question and added the script I was referring to